# How to remove redundancy from similar methods?

Tags: javascript, methods

Any creative suggestion on how to remove the redundancy of the methods within this object?:

```
var ObjectCrud = {
    createByKey: function(object, word, new_key, new_val) {
        return iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
            if (key === word) {
                obj[new_key] = new_val;
            }
        });
    },
    readByKey: function(object, word) {
        var object_array = [];
        iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
            if (key === word) {
                 object_array.push(obj);
            }
        });
        if (object_array.length > 0) { return object_array; }
    },
    updateByKey: function(object, word, update) {
        return iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
            if (key === word) {
                obj[key] = update;
            }
        });
    },
    deleteByKey: function(object, word) {
        return iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
            if (key === word) {
                delete obj[key];
            }
        });
    },
    createByValue: function(object, word, new_key, new_val) {
        return iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
            if (obj[key] === word) {
                obj[new_key] = new_val;
            }
        });
    },
    readByValue: function(object, word) {
        var object_array = [];
        iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
            if (obj[key] === word) {
                 object_array.push(obj);
            }
        });
        if (object_array.length > 0) { return object_array; }
    },
    updateByValue: function(object, word, update) {
        return iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
            if (obj[key] === word) {
                obj[key] = update;
            }
        });
    },
    deleteByValue: function(object, word) {
        return iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
            if (obj[key] === word) {
                delete obj[key];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My code works for me, I just feel like there's a more expressive way to write the methods listed above. For anyone wondering what this object would do, it's goal is to do operations that relate to the persistent storage concept on js objects.

Comment: What redundancy are you trying to remove? I feel like this is right on the line between useful abstraction and *too much* abstraction. As far as I can see, the redundancy you have is mostly in the `if` checks.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Yes, the redundant if checks for certain.  Also, I am curious as to how others might organize such code in a more meaningful way that what I have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you seem to want to abstract over your `iterativeFunction`, which *always* has a callback with an if-test.

So let's write a function for that (or two actually, as you once compare keys and once values).

```
function findKey(object, word, callback) {
    return iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
        if (key === word)
            callback(key, obj);
    });
}
function findValue(object, word, callback) {
    return iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
        if (obj[key] === word)
            callback(key, obj);
    });
}

var ObjectCrud = {
    createByKey: function(object, word, new_key, new_val) {
        return findKey(object, word, function(key, obj) {
            obj[new_key] = new_val;
        });
    },
    readByKey: function(object, word) {
        var object_array = [];
        findKey(object, word, function(key, obj) {
            object_array.push(obj);
        });
        if (object_array.length > 0) { return object_array; }
    },
    updateByKey: function(object, word, update) {
        return findKey(object, word, function(key, obj) {
            obj[key] = update;
        });
    },
    deleteByKey: function(object, word) {
        return findKey(object, word, function(key, obj) {
            delete obj[key];
        });
    },
    createByValue: function(object, word, new_key, new_val) {
        return findValue(object, word, function(key, obj) {
            obj[new_key] = new_val;
        });
    },
    readByValue: function(object, word) {
        var object_array = [];
        findValue(object, word, function(key, obj) {
            object_array.push(obj);
        });
        if (object_array.length > 0) { return object_array; }
    },
    updateByValue: function(object, word, update) {
        return findValue(object, word, function(key, obj) {
            obj[key] = update;
        });
    },
    deleteByValue: function(object, word) {
        return findValue(object, word, function(key, obj) {
            delete obj[key];
        });
    }
}
```

We also see that the callbacks are duplicated a lot. For `delete`, they're actually exactly the same, the others have duplicate bodies but differ in scope. Also, the `object` and `word` parameters, and the `findKey` and `iterativeFunction` calls are still copied everywhere (I actually used c&p in the above example).

Now, we can target that and make everything a little more concise by applying a bit of functional programming, or partial application to be exact:

```
function makefinder(compare) {
    return function makeCrud(callback) {
        return function(object, word, arg1, arg2) {
            return iterativeFunction(object, function (key, obj) {
                if (compare(key, obj, word))
                    callback(key, obj, arg1, arg2);
            });
        };
    };
}
var findKey = makeFinder(function(key, _, word) { return key===word; });
var findValue = makeFinder(function (key, obj, word) { return obj[key] === word; });

function create    (_,   obj, new_key, new_val) { obj[new_key] = new_val; }
function read      (key, obj, object_array)     { object_array.push(obj); }
function update    (key, obj, update)           { obj[key] = update; }
function deleteProp(key, obj)                   { delete obj[key]; }

function makeReader(finder) {
    var reader = finder(read);
    return function(object, word) {
        var array = [];
        reader(object, word, array);
        if (array.length) return array;
    };
}

var ObjectCrud = {
    createByKey: findKey(create),
    readByKey:   makeReader(findKey),
    updateByKey: findKey(update),
    deleteByKey: findKey(deleteProp),
    createByValue: findValue(create),
    readByValue:   makeReader(findValue),
    updateByValue: findValue(update),
    deleteByValue: findValue(deleteProp)
};
```

Surely you can also create that `ObjectCrud` by looping over a matrix with `[Key, Value]` in one and `[create, read, update, delete]` in the other dimension…